# Samsung SSD connected to Sata III but only shows Sata II

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, ssd

my laptop specifications state that I have a SATA III interface however Samsung Magician states I only have SATA II. I have tried updating all my drivers for the interface and I am still faced with this:
[image: magician]

My model is an HP Pavilion 15-n225nr TouchSmart Notebook PC:
[image: specs]
As you can see it clearly states that I have a SATA III 6Gbit/s interface. 
Cheers
<--Edit--> Adding HWInfo64 Pictures
[image: hwinfo]

Comment: where did you find this spec sheet for your laptop? I am looking at hp's spec page [here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04078962) and I don't see any mention of SATA III

Comment: I got it off of amazons spec sheet [here](http://www.amazon.com/HP-15-n225nr-15-Inch-Quad-Core-A10-5745M/dp/B00JBMF64I) I also edited my post with HWInfo64 stating I have SATA III

Comment: What makes you believe Samsung Magician is reporting correct information.  Have you done a benchmark on the drive?  Of course I see it another way, the amazon information is incorrect and HWiNFO64 is reporting bad information.

Comment: Could it be that the interface is capable of SATA III but it is set to SATA II in the BIOS? Unlikely, and I couldn't find instructions for the BIOS.

Comment: My bios is very limited and locked by HP. and @Ramhound my laptop was purchased late 2014. Every other website states I am running SATA III except Samsung Magician.

Comment: I still suggest doing a benchmark.

Comment: Now it is displaying I have a SATA III connection. I took the bios mode to legacy support and that seemed to do the trick. What would cause that?